Is there a hook to check if reindex build and start process failed?
Based on the Polarion docs to launch the reindex process https://docs.plm.automation.siemens.com/content/polarion/20/help/en_US/user_and_administration_help/administrators_guide/system_maintenance/index_and_reindex.html
is there a hook ( or similiar ) to check if the whole process failed? From the docs

The process writes messages to the console and the log4j-startup-TIMESTAMP.log file

I want to run some logic after Polarion finished the reindex and started the service. I only need to now if everything is fine or if something failed and which problems occured.
My idea was to create a shell script that runs the reindex script, stores the console output into a variable and inspects the output for a "success" information. If that doesn't exists, I need to search for the problem ( or take the whole output, but that would be some MB ). And AFAIK the Windows batch script ( reindex.bat ) does not write to the Console output stream, only the Linux one.
My second idea was to create a small app that runs the reindex script and tries to watch new log files. It will watch the newest one and waits for a "success" information. But there are several problems: My app can't know the file name of the log file, there might be multiple ones. And maybe my app can't find the log file because it will be created 3 seconds too late. And my app won't be able to know when everything is done and ready to be parsed...
So are there any ways to run logic ( shell script, code, ... ) after the process has finished?

You can monitor the
log4j-YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm-ss-startup.log, it states when reindexin is finished. You can then inspect the -error.log file, until this timestamp if anything critical happened.
Last but not least you can:

try to grab the URL of the Polarion System
log into the webservice / REST API and do some test queries.

